# ASCII triangle in J

Tags: ascii-art, j

I've been doing code golf puzzles to improve my J.  I'd appreciate any feedback on my solution to [this problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133688/15469).

The task is to take an integer and produce an ascii triangle as follows:

```
5 

|\    
| \   
|  \  
|   \ 
|    \
------
```

My solution:

```
(#&'| \' @ (1,1,~])"0 i.) , ('-'#~>:)
```

Comment: I think your answer fails for n=0. It should produce no output, but yours produces '-'  Your code golf submission has a clever version that miles  put in the comments. *,&'-' '|',.'\'{."0~_1-i.  and it passes for n=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the approach miles took on your code golf submission:

```
*,&'-' '|',.'\'{."0~_1-i
```

I shortened it slightly to this:

```
*,&'-' '|',.' \'{~=@i.
```

Both of the above pass n=0